# BlazeLayout rendering content to a dynamic template, but the content is appearing at the bottom of the document

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am attempting to render a template via FlowRouter and BlazeLayout.render() to a dynamic template. That dynamic template exists inside a Bootstrap container div. When the content is rendered, however, it is appended to the bottom of the DOM in a div id'd as "__blaze-root", outside of my Bootstrap container and therefore breaking my page layout.

My route:

```
 /*Public Routes*/
    FlowRouter.route( '/', {
        action: function() {
            BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {area: "main"})
        },
        name: "public"
    });
```

Template to be rendered:

```
<template name="mainLayout">
    TEST CONTENT TO BE RENDERED
</template>
```

And the page and dynamic template, named main, where it should be rendered:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Arena v.01</title>
</head>

<body id="mainPageBackground">
    <div class="container">
        {{> Navbar}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            TEST #2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What I am seeing, however, is the `"TEST CONTENT TO BE RENDERED"` text appears at the bottom left of the page, unconstrained by the bootstrap `"col-md-4"`. Post-render source provided below as an example.

```
...
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
             <---- This empty column div is where I would expect the content to render.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     TEST #2
  </div> 
</div> <--- This is the end of the <div class="container">
<div id="__blaze-root">TEST CONTENT TO BE RENDERED</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would someone be able to shed some light on why my rendered template is not appearing where the rendered template *should* appear? Thank you in advance!

My current Meteor package list:

```
accounts-password            1.1.4  Password support for accounts
aldeed:autoform              5.8.0* Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and automatic reactive validation.
aldeed:collection2           2.6.0* Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema         1.5.0  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and autoform.
blaze-html-templates         1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
ecmascript                   0.1.6  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
es5-shim                     4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.2.84  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
jquery                       1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
kadira:blaze-layout          2.3.0  Layout Manager for Blaze (works well with FlowRouter)
kadira:flow-router           2.10.0  Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor
meteor-base                  1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteortoys:allthings         2.3.1  Insanely Handy Development Tools
mobile-experience            1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                        1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
session                      1.1.1  Session variable
standard-minifiers           1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                      1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap               3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
```

Comment: I have found *a* solution, though I am hesitant to mark the problem as self-resolved until I have input on whether or not it is the accepted solution.

In client/index.js I have: `BlazeLayout.setRoot('#test');`

And I made the following change to the div containing my dynamic template.
`<div class="col-md-4" id="test">
{{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</div>`

    So is this the only way to get it to work, by manually changing the BlazeLayout root? What if I have two dynamic templates and I want to rendered different content into each one?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So this was me not understanding how BlazeLayout worked. My solution was to set the BlazeLayout root to a main div containing a master layout, and then inside that layout template I organized my dynamic templates. This fixed both my issue with content rendering at the bottom of the DOM as well as being limited to a single dynamic template by setting the BlazeLayout root to the div containing that single dynamic template.

index.html

```
<body id="mainPageBackground">
    <div class="container">
        {{> Navbar}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" id="test">
                {{> mainLayout }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

index.js

```
BlazeLayout.setRoot('#test');
```

mainLayout.html

```
<template name="mainLayout">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=test}}
        <br>
    {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
</template>

<template name="content">
    CONTENT HERE!
</template>

<template name="test">
    TEST HERE!
</template>
```

At this point my content is rendered into the correct area of the page and I can render multiple dynamic templates from one or more FlowRouter routes.